# Symfony causing redirect error with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, symfony-2.8

I've got symfony 2.8 running on a CentOS 7 virtual box. Right now when I try to go to my site I get an internal server error. When I inspected the logs it says:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error
```

I have the `LogLevel` in apache set to trace3 and it looks like there are a whole mess of redirects around app.php. I'm not sure what's happening. I haven't modified the .htaccess file that came with symfony. Here is my mod_rewrite block from the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here's my httpd.conf (Don't worry about any security concerns. This is a local install for dev purposes only)

```
# Security
ServerTokens OS
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable On

ServerName "dev.indygaa.vm"
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15


User apache
Group apache

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>


HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
LogLevel trace3
EnableSendfile On

#Listen 80


Include "/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.load"
Include "/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf"

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional "/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf"
```

I can't see where this redirect keeps happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Change your last `RewriteRule` to this:

```
RewriteRule !/app\.php$ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: That resulted in 404 Not Found for app.php

Comment: That simply means that `%{ENV:BASE}/app.php` (i.e. `app.php` in current directory) doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok. I have a suspicion in might not be trying to pull from the correct document root. How can I tell where it's trying to pull app.php from?

Comment: If `app.php` exists in same folder as `.htaccess` then you can try: `RewriteRule !^app\.php$ app.php [L,NC]`

Comment: I think I've found the issue. This vm is being initially setup using puppet, and I don't believe I had all the settings correct. It's looking in a subfolder for the index files that shouldn't exist.

Comment: oh ok, then better to use proper known path instead of `%{ENV:BASE}`